# Empty Array is Giving Warning for array_merge()

Tags: plugin-development

I have the following code to generate a custom post type object:

```
public function __construct( $name, $args = array(), $labels = array() ) {

    // Set Variables
    $this->post_type_name      = self::uglify( $name );
    $this->post_type_args      = $args;
    $this->post_type_lables    = $labels;
```

Later in in the class, I have a method that generates the labels with some defaults and then allows overrides to be passed in when a new instance of the class is created.

```
// Set labels with some defaults and merge in overrides
$labels = array_merge(

    // Default values
    array(
        'name'               => _x( $plural, 'Post Type General Name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( $name, 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New ', strtolower( $name ) ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New ' . $name ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit ' . $name ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New ' . $name ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All ' . $plural ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View ' . $name ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search ', $plural ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found in Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => $plural
    ),

    // Overrides
    $this->post_type_labels
);
```

While looking at the debug log in WordPress, I saw I was getting an error that Arguement #2, `$this->post_type_labels` was not an array even though if it is omitted in the creation, an empty array is passed in by default.

How do I clear this warning and make sure `$this->post_type_labels` *is* an array? I am NOT getting the same message with `$args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in line:

```
$this->post_type_lables    = $labels;
```

then, you use undeclared variable `$this->post_type_labels` as a second argument of `array_merge` function.

Comment: Ugh... I need to stop coding when the caffeine runs out... Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.